# Close a game in Godot

Tags: html, game-engine, godot

I'm creating a web game using Godot. 
For close the game, i tried to use `get_tree().quit()`. 
If I use it on the IDE, it works. When i tried it on my server (after exported the project) it doesn't work. 
I'm sure that Exporting setting are okay. 
How can I close the game? 
And, how can I add an hypertext link (similar to html `` tag)? 
Thanks for your answer and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 6):

### Exit the game

On the web, using

```
get_tree().quit()
```

Should work. That is, it should stop the runtime. The game will not continue running. *It does not close the browser tab. In fact, browsers have restriction on scripts closing tabs.*

**Note**: Make sure you are using Godot 3.2.3 or newer (see [#39604](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/39604)). *I tried it, it works.*

---

### Making a link

You can a [`LinkButton`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_linkbutton.html), which is a button that looks like an hyperlink. And you want to connect its `"pressed"` signal to a script where you use [`OS.shell_open`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-shell-open), for example:

```
OS.shell_open("https://example.com")
```

**Note**: This result in a new tab in web exports. On the desktop it opens the default browser.

---

### Navigating the browser

Since you ask about closing the game, and about making a link, I'll venture to guess that what you actually want is to navigate (leaving the game and going to another page).

In a web export, you can access the JavaScript runtime of the browser to do this.

In Godot 3 use [`JavaScript.eval`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_javascript.html#class-javascript-method-eval):

```
JavaScript.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
```

In Godot 4 use [`JavaScriptBridge.eval`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_javascriptbridge.html#class-javascriptbridge-method-eval) instead:

```
JavaScriptBridge.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
```

---

### Detecting Web Build

You can use [`OS.get_name`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-name) to identify the platform.

For example, you can do this:

*Godot 3*

```
if OS.get_name() == "HTML5":
   JavaScript.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
else:
   OS.shell_open("https://example.com")
```

*Godot 4*

```
if OS.get_name() == "Web":
   JavaScriptBridge.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
else:
   OS.shell_open("https://example.com")
```

Which will navigate the browser if this is a web build, but if it isn't, it will try to open the default browser.