# How to redirect to a website in Godot Web

Tags: web, godot

I'm planning on trying to see if it's possible to make a website in Godot(Yes, I know I shouldn't I just want to try just to try). I thinking about and looking over the features I need and I have one problem.

I just need a way for a person to press a button and get redirected to my itch games. I don't care if it creates a new tab or changes the current tab. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont export to web you can call

`OS.shell_open("url")`

Sadly this does not work in an html export. A solution I found for myself is the JavaScript Interface. As the name suggested it allows you to execute Javascript.

So to open a URL you could connect the pressed signal of a button to something like this:

```
if OS.has_feature('JavaScript'):
    JavaScript.eval("""
        window.open('https://google.com', '_blank').focus();
    """)
```

This will open a new tab in the active browser.

I also found an article on the godot site, basically asking the same question (https://godotengine.org/qa/46978/how-do-i-open-richtextlabel-bbcode-links-in-an-html5-export). Here they tried to use an RichTextLabel with BBCode.

The solution did not work for me, when I tested it, though.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments you can try `OS.shell_open`, for example:

```
OS.shell_open("https://example.com")
```

That only works if it is not an HTML export.

---

Your other alternative is to eval JavaScript, for example this navigates the current tab:

```
JavaScript.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
```

Which only works if it is an HTML export.

---

Since that only works for an HTML export and the other does not work on an HTML export... If you need both you can do this:

```
if OS.get_name() == "HTML5":
   JavaScript.eval("window.location.href='https://example.com'")
else:
   OS.shell_open("https://example.com")
```

*See also [Close a game in Godot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308678/402022).*